# Is it a good idea to use Gettext and ICU MessageFormat combined?

Tags: internationalization, gettext, icu

When I read about [Gettext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext) and [ICU MessageFormat](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse), both are always described as being opposed approaches to localization.

But I thought, that a combination of both would be an interesting idea: Use MessageFormat for formatting and Gettext to choose the right template based on the language. Along the lines of:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, lang)
output = MessageFormat(lang, gettext("There is {number 1} Foo in bar."), [1])
```

Are there obvious (or not so obvious) drawbacks of this method? Am I missing a central part of MessageFormat on how the translated templates are selected otherwise?

Answer (score 4):

The obvious problem with your method is how plural forms would be handled. Although ICU has built-in support for [CLDR's plural rules](http://unicode.org/repos/cldr-tmp/trunk/diff/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html), it is not as easy and flexible, as the one that gettext is using.
Basically, in gettext the translators may add as many plural forms as they need and it is governed by the selection rule in .po file header. It is both more flexible and more correct approach than using CLDR rules (which might be incorrect depending on the CLDR version).

Comment: I question that assertion in cases, where you have more than one parameters in your string: `X monkey(s) peel Y banana(s)`. This is exactly that scenario, when Gettext results in `if`/`else` hell, while MessageFormat might provide a one-sop solution: http://pastebin.com/yBf6AR8M

Comment: @Boldewyn: Well, the problem with using MessageFormat and ICU is, these rules are completely unreadable. To make it worse, most of the translators are not familiar with them and it is not that easy to explain how it works. There are also no possibility to modify plural rules (they are given), whereas you can do that with Gettext. Last, but not least, the case you mentioned is a good example of things to avoid. Not just because of plural forms, but also due to hard problems with grammatical cases. There are usually ways to write a message to avoid such scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I ask for a purpose. Basically, my Gettext-based code looks like this at the moment: https://github.com/Boldewyn/Codepoints.net/blob/master/codepoints.net/views/codepoint/info.php and it is all but nice to localize. (It isn't even possible to localize in anything non-english-like.) I'm searching for a way to solve this *within* the localization tool, e.g., by leveraging MessageFormat's choice mechanism. I'm also tempted to try Mozilla's new L20n approach, however there's no PHP implementation at the moment. (And I'm otherwise a huge Gettext fan by the way.)

Comment: "in gettext the translators may add as many plural forms as they need" - am curious about this. Would you ever need more plural forms than what CLDR has? In which language? But what I really want to say is, our translators struggle with this sort of thing, so I doubt we could ever teach them how to edit po files... :(